# MySQL: How to fetch data from two table and store into one table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1242

I have three table.2 data comes from 2 table and insert it into another table.
Let: tbl_id hold the field id and tbl_msg hold the field msg.

```
tbl_id               tbl_msg

id                   msg
------               --------
1234                 test_msg
5678
9876
```

Now my desired output should be in tbl_info

```
id    msg
---   -------
1234  test_msg
5678  test_msg
9876  test_msg
```

I write a query but its showing error that: Subquery returns more than 1 row.
My query is below:

**INSERT INTO tbl_info (id,msg) VALUES((SELECT id FROM tbl_id),(SELECT msg FROM tbl_msg))**

Comment: I can't understand the question.

Comment: Is there only one msg in tbl_msg? If not, which messages should be connected (joined) to which id's?

Comment: i just need to take the data from two table and insert data into another table.take the all id 's from tbl_id and get the msg from tbl_msg and insert into tbl_info all ids and msg together..that's it

Comment: let say their have only one msg.because their lot of data that i filtered by the query: SELECT msg FROM tbl_msg WHERE CURDATE()=DATE_FORMAT(date_time,'%Y-%m-%d') ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 1.So their do'nt have any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a single SELECT statement which returns teh rows exactly as you want them inserted.

The 2 inner selects you have return all the id's from tbl_id and all the msg from tbl_msg, which doesn't make much sense.

First write the select, e.g.:

```
SELECT tbl_id.id, tbl_msg.msg 
FROM tbl_id
JOIN tbl_msg ON tbl_id.fk = tbl_msg.fk
WHERE (...)
```

Then use it for the INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_info (id, msg)
SELECT tbl_id.id, tbl_msg.msg 
FROM tbl_id
JOIN tbl_msg ON tbl_id.fk = tbl_msg.fk
WHERE (...)
```

---

**UPDATE** according to OP's comments:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_info (id, msg)
 SELECT tbl_id.id, single_msg.msg 
 FROM tbl_id
 JOIN (SELECT msg 
      FROM tbl_msg 
      WHERE CURDATE()=DATE_FORMAT(date_time,'%Y-%m-%d') 
      ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 1) as single_msg ON 1=1;
```

This will not be very efficient because the inner select will be executed for each record in tbl_id. A more efficient solution may be:

```
SELECT msg INTO @msg
FROM tbl_msg 
WHERE CURDATE()=DATE_FORMAT(date_time,'%Y-%m-%d') 
ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 1;

INSERT INTO tbl_info (id, msg)
    SELECT tbl_id.id, @msg 
    FROM tbl_id;
```

Comment: i can't use any foreign key here..Without foreign key i have to do it.IS their any other way to do it??i mean without using foreign key

Comment: It doesn't have to be a real foreign key - see updated answer

Comment: Dear @GAlz, Many many many thanks for your last solution.It's working properly as i want.thanks again for your time and help.